# What with start point coordinate on mac os?

Tags: swift, macos, nsbezierpath

What's going on?
I want customize macOS button with swift 3. macOS (0.0, 0.0) point is in bottom left corner. But when I write this code:

```
    let path = NSBezierPath()
    path.lineWidth = 2

    path.move(to: NSPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
    path.line(to: NSPoint(x: 0.0, y: 1.0))
    path.close() 

    NSColor.red.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
```

My start (0.0, 0.0) point is in top left corner, why?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on the view in which this path is embedded?

Comment: @Sparky it's NSButton. style: square, type: momentary push in, bordered: false. I has created my own class, where override drawRect method with code that presented above

Comment: show us the full code of the overridden function draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)

Comment: @user3441734, it's all that I have in draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)

Comment: @Anthony your code doesn't draw anything. You created closed path with points 0,0 0,1 0,0. Where is your drawing code?

Comment: @user3441734 yes, I missed last lines

Comment: Do you override `isFlipped`?

Comment: @algrid, no, but it return 'true' for me, it's strange. maybe it's default in swift 3?

Comment: @Anthony this means that your parent class returns true. What's your parent class?

Comment: @algrid parent class is NSButton

Comment: @Anthony https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35896226/paintcode-nsbutton-displays-upside-down

Comment: @algrid, thank you so much!